# c# Json Implicit Newtonsoft DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

With Newtonsoft I know I can declare typed class and deserialize json into concrete classes... is there a way to implicitly deserialize json and allow the newtonsoft assembly do the work to infer the json types?

Comment: Newtonsoft has a whole library of types for working with raw json without concrete classes, JObject JArray JToken etc... is this the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: If you get this working, how would you expect to use the objects returned considering you don't know the type?

Comment: Define what you mean by _"infer the json types"_. Do you mean you want to feed it a series of types, and that it'll guess which type best matches the passed JSON?

Comment: Are you looking for something that can generate the C# types for you? https://app.quicktype.io?share=O7OBJHPU9mRlz6yvLmD4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always deserialize any JSON. But to use it you need to know its structure.

For example, codes below will deserialize and displays any JSON into the console

```
void UnpackJson(JToken jobj, int indent)
{
    if (jobj == null)
        return;

    var name = (jobj as JProperty)?.Name;
    if (name != null)
    {
        Console.Write(new string(' ', indent) + name + " :\n");
        indent += 4;
    }

    foreach (var child in jobj.Children())
    {
        var chname = (child as JProperty)?.Name;
        if (chname != null)
            Console.Write(new string(' ', indent) + chname + " : ");

        var value = (child as JProperty)?.Value;
        if (child.Values().Count() > 1)
        {
            if (chname != null || name != null)
                Console.WriteLine();

            IEnumerable<JToken> jt = (value is JArray) ? child.Values() : child.Children();

            foreach (var val in jt)
                UnpackJson(val, indent + 4);
        }
        else
        {
            if (value != null)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be called as follows:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);  
UnpackJson(obj, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON.NET can do a lot of type inference in an object hierarchy, but it needs to know at least the top-level object type. Otherwise the deserialized object will be dynamic. An example of statically typed deserialization is below:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Bar = new Bar { Message = "Message" }
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    var foo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);

    //foo == foo2 here
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where's the type inference?

Comment: What if `Bar` is abstract (or an interface) and there are multiple possible concrete implementations? There is no type inference here.